# Ansible - Compare checksum on 2 lists of files

Tags: ansible

I want to use Ansible to compare all specific files in one folder to all specific files in another folder between 2 remote hosts

I tried 'stat' 'file' modules.
I can get a list of files and their corresponding checksum, but I cannot find a way to loop through the list to compare checksum to checksum per file.

I want to be able to quickly identify differences in files so as to update servers as necessary

Comment: I thought about writing out the [`with_together`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/plugins/lookup/together.html) example but are you sure you don't just want `rsync -Pauv --dry-run` and deal with the output from that? It seems like a ton less trouble than hand-rolling a solution using jinja2

Comment: I'll test that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks.  That worked on some other tasks that I needed help on.  I use it now to create csv's for reporting what I compare.

Answer (score 0):

The playbook below works for me. Let's register the status of the files in the first play for all hosts in the group 'test' and compare the status of the hosts 'test_01' and 'test_02' in the second play.

```
- hosts: test
  vars:
    files:
      - /scratch/testA/file1
      - /scratch/testA/file2
      - /scratch/testA/file3
  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ files }}"
      register: status_of_files

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        list1: "{{ hostvars['test_01'].status_of_files.results|
                 json_query('[].{item: item, hash: stat.checksum}') }}"
    - set_fact:
        list2: "{{ hostvars['test_02'].status_of_files.results|
                 json_query('[].{item: item, hash: stat.checksum}') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list1 | difference(list2) }}"
```

The variation of the second play below declares the host 'test_01' a master and compares all other hosts from the group 'test' to the master.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    master: test_01
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        master_list: "{{ hostvars[master].status_of_files.results|
                         json_query('[].{item: item, hash: stat.checksum}') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ master_list|
                 difference(hostvars[item_host].status_of_files.results|
                 json_query('[].{item: item, hash: stat.checksum}')) }}"
      loop: "{{ groups['test'] |  difference([ master ]) }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item_host
```

> To compare **all specific files in one folder** to **all specific files in another folder** between 2 remote hosts.

Let's create a variable with the path to the folder

```
$ cat hosts
[test]
test_01 my_folder=/scratch/testA
test_02 my_folder=/scratch/testB
test_03 my_folder=/scratch/testC
```

and create the list of files in the first play

```
- hosts: test
  tasks:
    - find:
        path: "{{ my_folder }}"
      register: list_of_files
    - set_fact:
        files: "{{ list_of_files.files|
                   json_query('[].path')|
                   map('basename')|
                   list }}"
    - stat:
        path: "{{ my_folder }}/{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ files }}"
      register: status_of_files
```

Then use the *symmetric_difference* filter in the second play

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ list1 | symmetric_difference(list2) }}"
```

or

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ master_list|
             symmetric_difference(hostvars[item_host].status_of_files.results|
             json_query('[].{item: item, hash: stat.checksum}')) }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['test'] | difference([ master ]) }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item_host
```

Comment: I may have posted a follow on question the wrong way.

Comment: Here is the summary:   0


I was able to compare 1 folder per host. If I have 2 folders per host, how do I compare the second folder? Example: I have 4 servers for each environment - UAT and SIT. Each server runs 2 instances of the application server thus needing 2 separate folders containing the .war files. I have one server as master, but that server also have 2 folders, thus needing to compare.

Answer (score 0):

#### Playbook to compare files in N number of hosts

```
- name: Compare files from each host in hosts file
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    files:
      - /tmp/file1
      - /tmp/file2
      - /tmp/file3
  tasks:
    - name: Get file info
      stat:
        path: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ files }}"
      register: p
    - name: Save in required format
      set_fact:
        result: "{{ result|default([]) + [ {item.item: { inventory_hostname: { 'checksum': item.stat.checksum if item.stat.exists == true else 'File does not exists'} } } ] }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ p.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"

- name: Merge results in ansible machine
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Combine Result
      set_fact:
         value: "{{ value|default([{}]) | combine(hostvars[item].result, recursive=True) }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ groups['all'] }}"
    - name: Final result
      debug:
        msg: "{{ value }}"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compare 1 folder per host.
If I have 2 folders per host, how do I compare the second folder?
Example:  I have 4 servers for each environment - UAT and SIT. Each server runs 2 instances of the application server thus needing 2 separate folders containing the .war files.
I have one server as master, but that server also have 2 folders, thus needing to compare.

```
# --- first ---

- name: Find all files
  find:
    path: "{{ my_folder }}"
  register: list_of_files

- name: set_fact - basename all files  
  set_fact:
    files: "{{ list_of_files.files|
               json_query('[].path')|
               map('basename')|
               list }}"               

- name: stat files from set_fact
  stat:
    path: "{{ my_folder }}/{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ files }}"
  register: status_of_files

# --- second ---

- name: set_fact for master_list
  set_fact:
    master_list: "{{ hostvars[master].status_of_files.results|
                     json_query('[].{item: item, hash: stat.checksum}') }}"

- name: debug - set_fact for master_list                     
  debug:
    msg: "{{ master_list|
             symmetric_difference(hostvars[item_host].status_of_files.results|
             json_query('[].{item: item, hash: stat.checksum}')) }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['FS-AA-PERF-WAS'] | difference([ master ]) }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item_host
```